# Raspbian Stretch Lite with Touchscreen - Chromium "Couldn't initialize SDL: No available video device"

Tags: raspbian-stretch, touchscreen, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, with the RPi 7-inch touchscreen hooked up.

I installed Raspbian Stretch Lite on a 16GB SD card. I have booted the Raspberry Pi, changed my password, connected to Wifi, and enabled SSH. I updated and upgraded the OS, and then installed chromium (`sudo apt-get install chromium-bsu`).

I am trying to run Chromium, `chromium-bsu`, and get the following:

```
Couldn't initialize SDL: No available video device
```

I don't want all the other crap that comes with the full version of *Raspbian Stretch*. I don't want the Debian GUI, I do not want Mathematica, I do not want whatever else they throw in there. Can I get to where I need to be, without the full version? What packages can I install to get between here and there?

I am a newb, and have no idea what to do here. I cannot find anything online about this. I don't even know what SDL is, or what the purpose of it is. Any help?

Comment: I am having the same problem trying to run MAME. I've tried quite a few different solutions without success. I am pretty sure you need a distro with a GUI. You could always find a small one and then reduce it as much as possible after you get things running. Did you ever find a solution for a no-GUI distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using *Raspbian Stretch Lite* that has no graphical support but `chromium-bsu` needs it. It's a game with GUI. To install and play it you need the full version of *Raspbian Stretch* with graphical support.

**Update:**
If you do not want all the overhead from *Raspbian Stretch* you can try to install the missing [**S**imple **D**irectMedia **L**ayer (SDL)](https://www.libsdl.org/index.php). There are some libraries from this. Look with `apt list libsdl2*` what's available. I think **libsdl2-2.0-0** is the first library you want to install. This will also install the needed X11-server for graphics support and will install a lot of dependent packets. You can look what will happen without really install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt --simulate install libsdl2-2.0-0
```

If you are sure to install all this packets (and maybe brake your installation?) then simply omit the `--simulate` option.

Seems not to be a simple task for a newb if it doesn't run on the first try ;-)
Maybe you have to install additional libraries from *libsdl2*.

Comment: I don't want all the other crap that comes with the full version. I dont want the Debian GUI, I do not want Mathematica, I do not want whatever else they throw in there. Can I get to where I need to be, without the full version? What packages can I install to get between here and there?

Comment: @lukehawk Yes, I can understand it. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am probably in over my head, but that's pretty much where I live..

Comment: I ran this and installed SDL and it still gives the error. The installation did not break, but the same error message is applied. Do I need to do something else to configure SDL?

Comment: @LoganKitchen I never had used SDL so I'm afraid I cannot help much. Seems there is a problem with your display. You may have a look at google `Couldn't initialize SDL: No available video device`.

Comment: No worries. I did a pretty extensive search of "Couldn't initialize SDL No available video device" and tried everything that I found to no avail. I think I am just going to use Raspbian Stretch with the desktop. It still is a pretty minimal distro and I can remove the things that I don't need.